# How to localize a newly created storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard

I have simply created a new Single App project in Xcode 10.1. Then I have created a new storyboard named "Login.storyboard". I want to localise my project and to do that I have tried adding a new language from "Localizations" in project property but it shows me a list with only two storyboard "Main.storyboard" and "LaunchScreen.storyboard".

Please suggest how I can enable localization for newly created storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps.

- Select *Login.storyboard* in *Project Navigator*.
- Go to the *File Inspector*.
- At the bottom you should see a *Localization Section*, with a big *Localize...* button.
- Click on the button, and Xcode will ask you for which language.
- Select *base* and then click in *Localize*.

After following these steps you should be able to also localize your new storyboard in *Localizations* at your project properties.